# UITableViewCell created from XIB doesn't show content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a `UITableVIewCell` from a `XIB` file. However, it doesn't get displayed on the application.

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.tablev registerClass:[MCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"c"];

     MCell *cell = (MCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c"];

    if (cell == nil)

    {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = (MCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    cell.la.text=@"This is from custom cell";

    //cell.textLabel.text=@"from label";

    return cell;
```

The text `This is from custom cell` doesn't get displayed. But, `cell.textLabel.text=@"from label";` gets executed perfectly and displays the text. I think my `UITableViewCell` hasn't got initialised in the code. Can someone look into this ?

Comment: u were added the datasource=self; in viewdidload

Comment: in `initWithFrame`. This is a `UIView` that i am using to display the table.

Comment: did you override method `initWithStyle: reuseidentifier:` and load nib in your custom cell class yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put this method

```
[self.tablev registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MCell"
               bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"c"];
```

in your `viewDidLoad:` or `awakeFromNib:` if you are using tableView in an `UIView` XIB file or any initializing method where you **initialize** your other properties and variables.

and in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, do the following

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     MCell *cell = (MCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c"];

    cell.la.text=@"This is from custom cell";
    //cell.textLabel.text=@"from label";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i dont have a viewdidload, i only have initwithframe. Is it ok if i add it to initwithframe?

Comment: Then in awakeFromNib: if you are using UIView

Answer (score 0):

You might need to register your nib file:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MCell"
                bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                forCellReuseIdentifier:@"c"];
```